# Calculate the length of the curve in the pdf file drawn with TCPDF

Tags: php, image-processing, tcpdf

i need to Calculate the length of the curve in the pdf file drawn with tcpdf
i draw this curves with curve function of TCPDF and should control length of them but i dont know how to do this!

I need to get length of curves in this image:

[image]

first i try to read pdf file in actual size and count the number of black dots of curve to calculate length of arc but i can not read pdf generated file in php then i try to develop function that can draw curve .this function draw curve by mixing Line and Circle functions of TCPDF but there was problem to act same as curve function please guide me if there is way to callculate length of arc